# Can a forward pass be thrown after a handoff made in front of the quarterback?

Tags: rules, american-football

The quarterback hands the ball to a receiver; the handoff is in front of the quarterback but behind the line of scrimmage, which is a legal play.

Can the receiver now throw a forward pass?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Like already explained in my other [answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/17542/is-there-such-a-thing-as-an-ineligible-runner-in-football), the [Hand-Off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand-off) is not a pass, so yes... a pass may still be thrown as long as the [passing rules](http://edge-operations.nfl.com/the-rules/2017-nfl-rulebook/#article-2.-legal-forward-pass) are met (only one forward pass per play, ball didn't cross the line before, etc).

> Handing the ball is transferring player possession from one teammate
>   to another without passing or kicking it. ([Rules Section 15](http://edge-operations.nfl.com/the-rules/2017-nfl-rulebook/#section-15-handling-the-ball))

There is no statement in the rules of (in)eligible pass throwers, so anyone may do so.

Also Julian Edelman (Wide Receiver) threw a TD pass in 2015: [Ravens vs Patriots](http://www.espn.com/nfl/game?gameId=400749515)

Answer (score -3):

No, it'd be **illegal**.  If the hand off is forward, it counts as a forward pass. If the receiver of that forward hand off then throws a forward pass it'd be considered the *second* forward pass of the play and thus be **illegal**.

Comment: As with the other (contradictory) answer, could you quote the specific points from the rulebook you are basing this on?

Comment: The other answer quotes and refers to a rule which states that a handoff is a transfer between players which **is not** a pass or kick. Your answer is factually wrong.

Comment: A forward handoff has its own rules, but is still not considered a pass.